# Probability of drawing a white ball the first and third time

Tags: probability

An urn contains 10 balls (6 white ones and 4 red ones). What are the odds that we draw three white balls in total and the first and third balls are white?

I would say we're looking at {${W,W,W,R}$} and {$W,R,W,W$}, but since there are $4$ red balls we have to multiply with $4$. So there are $2*4=8$ possible outcomes and our sample space is $10 \choose 4$. The probability would then be: $\frac{8}{10 \choose 4}$. However, the solution manual states that there are only 2 possible outcomes, and that I don't have to multiply with $4$.

Can somebody explain to me why we disregard the red balls in this example? If we were to draw $n$ red balls and $k$ white balls, we would calculate: $\frac{{6 \choose k} {4 \choose n}}{10 \choose n+k}$. So howcome we don't do the same thing in the example above?

Comment: The problem does not explicitly say so, but it looks as if you are assuming we are drawing $4$ balls,  without replacement.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I preassume that $4$ balls are drawn without replacement (not mentioned in your question).

The probability of drawing exactly $3$ white balls is: $$\frac{\binom63\binom41}{\binom{10}4}$$ In $2$ of the $4$ equiprobable cases $(W,W,W,R),(W,W,R,W),(W,R,W,W),(R,W,W,W)$ the first and the third ball are white, so we end up with probability:$$\frac24\frac{\binom63\binom41}{\binom{10}4}$$

Answer (score 0):

The desired probability can indeed be computed considering only $2$ cases:

{${W,W,W,R}$} and {$W,R,W,W$},  $Pr = 2\times\dfrac6{10}\dfrac5{9}\dfrac48\dfrac47$